# C2084 - function already has a body

Tags: c++, virtual

I'm running into an error ***"C2084 - function 'void Pet::display(void)' already has a body"***. Error occurs on Dog.cpp file. Slightly confused about the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

---

**Pet.h**

```
#ifndef _PET_H_
#define _PET_H_

#include <string>
using namespace std;

enum Type { dog = 0, cat };

class Pet {
private:
    string name, breed; // private local variables
    Type type;

public:
    Pet(string pet_name, string pet_breed, Type pet_type); // constructor

    // accessor methods
    string getName();
    string getBreed();
    Type getType();

    virtual void display() {};
};

#endif // _PET_H_
```

**Dog.h**

```
#ifndef _DOG_H_
#define _DOG_H_

#include "Pet.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Dog : public Pet {
public:
    Dog(string pet_name, string pet_breed, Type pet_type) : Pet(pet_name, pet_breed, pet_type) {
    } // constructor

    virtual void display() = 0;

};

#endif
```

**Dog.cpp**

```
#include "Dog.h"
#include "Pet.h"
#include <iostream>

void Pet::display() {
    cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
    cout << "Breed: " << breed << endl;
    cout << "Type: Dog" << endl;
}
```

Comment: I suspect that in `Pet.h`  you give a body to `Pet::display`

Comment: I just posted Pet.h code. Yes, there is a virtual void display() {}; in Pet.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you wanted to define Dog::display and have forgotten to rename Pet to Dog:

```
void Dog::display() {
    cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
    cout << "Breed: " << breed << endl;
    cout << "Type: Dog" << endl;
}
```

Also remove " = 0" from:

```
virtual void display() = 0;
```

in "Dog.h".

In "Pet.h" file having " = 0" after function prototype is ok, it means that you shouldn't instantiate the Pet class directly (Abstract class).

Answer (score 1):

In `Pet.h` you already have a body defined for `display()`, which does nothing.

In **`Pet.h`**:

```
class Pet {
    /* other class members */
    virtual void display() {}; // Here is your virtual function with an empty body.
};
```

In **`Dog.h`**:

```
class Dog : public Pet {
    /* other class members */
    virtual void display() = 0; // This pure virtual function which is inheriting from Pet which is not purely virtual.

};
```

Swap the two around.

- Make `Pet`'s `virtual void display() = 0`, i.e. a pure virtual function.
- Make `Pet`'s `virtual void display()`, i.e. a virtual function which you are already implementing in Dog.cpp.

---

**Solution:**

In **`Pet.h`**:

```
class Pet {
    /* other class members */
    virtual void display() = 0; // Make this a pure virtual function. It does not have an implementation.
};
```

In **`Dog.h`**:

```
class Dog : public Pet {
    /* other class members */
    virtual void display(); // This virtual function is implemented in Dog.cpp.

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the method `display` pure virtual in the class `Dog` which is derived from another class `Pet`. But the `Pet` class already has a concrete method called `display`. That' why you get this error.

Declare `display` as pure virtual in the `Pet` class and then give a concrete implementation in its child class `Dog`.

Comment: I see. Pet.h class has been posted. It does have a virtual void display() {};

Comment: I see your edited code. Now you are declaring `Pet::display` twice. One with an empty body (as virtual) and another with an implementation. You can't have the same method with the same arguments declared twice in a given class.